# How to add meta data in laravel api resource

Tags: php, laravel, api

I using laravel api resource for my FRONT-END site.

Actually i using also laravel pagination to handle paginate in FRONT-END.

The api resource structure like this:

```json
{
    "data": [...],
    "links": [...], // handle pagination
    "meta": [...] // handle pagination
}
```

But i want to send count of query results without considering paginating .For example i paginating database result into `30 pre_page` and the all of query result is
`200` and i want to send this count to view front-end

I decided to get count of query result and give to resource collection and restructure laravel api resource to this.

```json
{
    "data": [...],
    "metadata": {
        "count": 200
    },
    "links": [...], // handle pagination
    "meta": [...] // handle pagination
}
```

Also you sould know maybe i want to add another data to this collection. for example `conversion rate` in addition count to `metadata` and i don't know how do this.

Answer (score 5):

I find the way hou can i do this

Actually i just have to use `additional` method for laravel resource like:

```php
$data = Project::limit(100)->get();
return ProjectResource::collection($data)->additional(['some_id => 1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [top-level-meta-data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#top-level-meta-data).

You need to create a `ResourceCollection` and then define the additional meta variables in the `with` function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class UserCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
    * Transform the resource collection into an array.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return array
    */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }

    /**
    * Get additional data that should be returned with the resource array.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return array
    */
    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'key' => 'value',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```