# Add meta data from laravel collection to resource?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-collection, laravel-resource

I have a laravel collection and its resource, to laravel collection I'm adding meta data.

I'm trying to add it like stated in multiple source like [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data) or this [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70727830/how-to-add-meta-data-in-laravel-api-resource) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70727830/how-to-add-meta-data-in-laravel-api-resource).

```
$metaData = ['total' => $elements->count(), 'active_element_id' => $activeElement];

NaviItemResource::collection($elements)->additional([$metaData])
```

I see this in `additional` data from collection, but I would need it also in Resource file like stated on image.

Is that possible to add in resource as well?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT4eQ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.